# Press UIImage to open new view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiimage

I have the following code and would like to open a specific view controller when images 1,2 or 3 is pressed. Please can you provide me with a sample code to accomplish this. Thank you

```
UIImage *startImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"start"];
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-demo1"];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-demo2"];
    UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-demo3"];
    NSArray *images = @[image1, image2, image3];
    SphereMenu *sphereMenu = [[SphereMenu alloc] initWithStartPoint:CGPointMake(160, 320)
                                                         startImage:startImage
                                                      submenuImages:images];
```

Comment: You are showing these images in one imageview or in 3 different imageViews?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use this control as my main navigation menu https://github.com/itouch2/SphereMenu I am not sure. it was done programmatically and not with storyboard

Comment: Why not use a button and just set the image on the button?

Answer (score 3):

You should implement `SphereMenuDelegate` protocol and
`- (void)sphereDidSelected:(int)index;`   method

```
      sphereMenu.delegate = self;    

//...
- (void)sphereDidSelected:(int)index
{
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // image1 selected
            break;
        case 1:
            // image2 selected
            break;
        case 2:
            // image3 selected
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just drag three button on ViewController(in storyboard) set image for button.
drag and drop segue for three button to three ViewControllers.

Comment: There is a start image that once pressed it shoots out 3 more images that I want to be able to press to go to a new view controller https://github.com/itouch2/SphereMenu

Answer (score 0):

Implement `SphereMenuDelegate delegate` and copy that method

```
  func sphereDidSelected(index: Int) {
    println("image Clicked")
  }
```

You will get `click event` on that image.